# Why does my function sometimes respect whitespace?

Tags: key-bindings, functions

I have a few functions to help with adding PHP docblock tags. Suppose a block like this:

```php
/**
 * Does a thing
 *
 * |
 */
```

Where `|` is my cursor position. I have a mapping to `<localleader>@p`, for instance, to insert an `@package` tag:

```php
 * @package foo-bar
```

#### Function

Here's my basic function:

```
function! MaybeSetPackage()
    if ! exists( "g:php_package" )
        let l:package = ''
    else
        let l:package = g:php_package
    endif

    execute ':normal! a@package ' . l:package
endfunction
```

#### Expectation

When I move to a line in the docblock and type `\@p`, this should be the result:

```php
/**
 * Does a thing
 *
 * @package foo-bar
 */
```

#### What sometimes happens

If I'm on a line in NORMAL mode, like:

```php
/**
 * Does a thing
 * |
 */
```

And hit `o`, I'm here:

```php
/**
 * Does a thing
 *
 * |
 */
```

And then, while still in INSERT mode, I type `\@p`, I get this:

```php
/**
 * Does a thing
 *
 *@package foo-bar
 */
```

However, if I type `o`, delete the space after `*`, type a new space, and *then* do `\@p`, I get this:

```php
/**
 * Does a thing
 *
 * @package foo-bar
 */
```

#### Why?

Why, after hitting `o` and getting

```
 * |
```

does my function seem to remove the automatically inserted space and leave me with

```
 *@package foo-bar
```

but when I delete the automatically inserted space and add my own, followed by my mapping, I get the expected result of

```
 * @package foo-bar
```

?

#### Update

Adding my mapping:

```
    autocmd FileType php inoremap <buffer> <localleader>@p <esc>:call MaybeSetPackage()<CR>
```

Comment: Irrelevant side note: check out the `get()` function

Comment: @D.BenKnoble added my mapping.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important part of the question is missing: The mapping. I assume the following:

```
inoremap <localleader>@p <C-O>:call MaybeSetPackage()<CR>
```

The point here is, that you are leaving insert mode (here with `<C-O>`) and Vim automatically removes spaces that were added by automatic indent. If you add the spaces yourself, they are not removed.

So you need to insert text *without* leaving insert mode.

**Inserting the expression register**

The "expression register" can be inserted with `<C-R>=...`. This is not really a register, you have to provide the expression. 
Your mapping might than be:

```
inoremap <localleader>@p @package <C-R>=exists("g:php_package")?g:php_package:''<CR>
```

or, if you want to keep your function:

```
function! MaybeSetPackage()
    if ! exists( "g:php_package" )
        let l:package = ''
    else
        let l:package = g:php_package
    endif
    " Now returns the text to insert
    return '@package ' . l:package
endfunction


inoremap <localleader>@p <C-R>=MaybeSetPackage()<CR>
```

See `:help i_Ctrl-R_=` for the details.

**Map-Expressions**

Another way would be to use a `map-<expr>`. This type of maps, maps to a Vim script expression, that returns the characters (or keystrokes) that Vim should interpret. In the following case the `@package ...` characters are returned and as it is a input-mapping, they are inserted in the buffer. Again, you can put the Vim script code directly into the mapping or call a function.

```
inoremap <expr> \@p '@package ' . (exists('g:php_package')?g:php_package:'')
inoremap <expr> \@P MaybeSetPackage()
```

See `:help map-<expr>` for details.

---

**BTW: Using `get()`**

@D.BenKnoble mentioned `get()` in the comments. This is a function to search for an entry in a dictionary. It can be used in the following way:

```
get(g:, 'php_package', '')
```

In this case `g:` is the dictionary of all global variables. Now `get()` searches for the entry `php_package` in this dictionary. If found the variable value is returned, else the default value (`''`).

So the above mapping could be written as:

```
inoremap <expr> \@p '@package ' . get(g:,'php_package','')
```

This works, is very compact and (if you know what it is doing) easy to understand.

Comment: Same comment for OP: `get()` simplifies some of the logic here.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble See update

Comment: These definitely simplify the logic, I'll try them out!